# wordpress custom post title viewer development

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to create something like this in wordpress, so that in a wordpress page I can show users the post titles which are linked to their post links and also the date of those posts.
what kind of code should I use in wordpress? 
 I am new to wordpress coding.
 so please give me some sample code so that I can use.

 also I want to choose posts from one special category. how can I do that?
 is there any wordpress plugin which does this?

 pagination links are also important to have.

Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look into [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query). It may take a little while to get used to it but it lets you echo all the data you want. I use it for almost everything now.

In the `$args` array you define what you want to query (such as posts from a specific category, how many, in what order), and then from there you can pull the title, the date published, the attachments, the excerpt, featured image, etc.

```
<?php
// The Query
$args = array(
    'numberposts' => '5',
    'category_name' => 'my-category', // the slug
    'offset' => '0',
    'orderby' => 'post_date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();
} else {
    // no posts found
}
?>
```

The great part about WP_query is that you can use it to have multiple loops on 1 template. This would replace the normal loop in the template.

For date, you would use [the_date()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_date) or `get_the_date()`. So you might do an

```
echo '<p><span class="date">' . get_the_date() . '</span> <a class="my-title" href="' . get_the_title() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></p>';
```

There's more than one way to do this (and almost everything) in WordPress, so it depends on what you're doing and what else is going on in the code. There's `query_posts()` and `wp_get_recent_posts()`... really there's too many to mention. I'd post more links but my rep isn't high enough to.

I'd start looking into WP_Query as you can pull whatever data you want from that and format it to your heart's content.

Anyway, hope this well help you.

Comment: Also it would be a good idea to look into some base theme templates to start with. These will give you some good functions and such as a starting point, the base theme files, and won't be cluttered with crap. Most these days include modernizr for fallbacks, google fonts enques, and all types of stuff so you don't have to build your theme from scratch. They should also have pagination included.